# How to listen only to fresh events on private besu blockchain?

Tags: events, synchronization, besu

Is it possible to listen only to new events by Besu plugin, and bypass events, that are coming when synchronizing a node to a blockchain? I use [`Log listener`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.hyperledger.besu/plugin-api/latest/org/hyperledger/besu/plugin/services/BesuEvents.LogListener.html) to listen to incoming events.

Comment: The best is probably to check if the node is synced before handling events. You can't really know what's new or not. Everything is new from a freshly syncing node perspective.